# PCA Dimensionality Reduction

Tags: java, matlab, machine-learning, linear-algebra, pca

I am trying to perform [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) reducing 900 dimensions to 10. So far I have:

```
covariancex = cov(labels);
[V, d] = eigs(covariancex, 40);

pcatrain = (trainingData - repmat(mean(traingData), 699, 1)) * V;
pcatest = (test - repmat(mean(trainingData), 225, 1)) * V;
```

Where `labels` are `1x699` labels for chars (1-26). `trainingData` is `699x900`, 900-dimensional data for the images of 699 chars. `test` is `225x900`, 225 900-dimensional chars.

Basically I want to reduce this down to `225x10` i.e. 10 dimensions but am kind of stuck at this point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The covariance is supposed to implemented in your `trainingData`:

```
X = bsxfun(@minus, trainingData, mean(trainingData,1));           
covariancex = (X'*X)./(size(X,1)-1);                 

[V D] = eigs(covariancex, 10);   % reduce to 10 dimension

Xtest = bsxfun(@minus, test, mean(trainingData,1));  
pcatest = Xtest*V;
```

Comment: Sorry just one more thing, I remember why I used 40 originally (although I do not need that many) because according to my lecturer, it is better to take dimensions 2:11 rather than 1:10, how would I achieve this?

Comment: [V D]=eigs(covariancex,11); pcatest=Xtest*V(:,2:11);

Answer (score 1):

From your code it seems like you are taking the covariance of the `labels`, not the `trainingData`. I believe the point of PCA is in determining the greatest variance in some N (N = 10 here) number of subspaces of your data.

Your covariance matrix should be 900x900 (if 900 is the dimension of each image, a result of having 30x30 pixel images I assume.) Where the diagonal elements `[i,i]` of `covaraincex` gives the variance of that pixel for all training samples, and off diagonal `[i,j]` give the covariance between pixel `i` and pixel `j`. This should be a diagonal matrix as `[i,j] == [j,i].`

Furthermore when calling `eigs(covariancex,N)`, N should be 10 instead of 40 if you want to reduce the dimension to 10.

Comment: Sorry, I remember why I used 40 originally (although I do not need that many) because according to my lecturer it is better to take dimensions 2:11 rather than 1:10, how would I achieve this?